# htaccess / mod_rewrite for Search Engine Friendly URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of files in the web root: -

/abc-674.php
/def-643.php
etc.etc.

I want to show these when the following URL's are requested, without changing the URL in the browser: -

/products/abc-674/this_can_be_anything.php
/products/abc-674/or_this.php

both redirect to /abc-674.php, and

/products/def-643/this_can_be_anything.php
/products/def-643/or_this.php

both redirect to /def-643.php.

So, basically, the bit between **products/** and the next **/** is the target, while anything after that can effectively be ignored.

If it matters, I've already got a little code in my .htaccess to direct all traffic to my preffered domain (with www): -

```
# Direct all traffic to domain.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: To clarify - the 2nd last line in the above is because I access the site on my dev server via http://domain/ only, and so don't want that rewrite to apply for those requests. I do, however, want this new rewrite to apply to all requests.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can use the next rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([\d\w]+)/(.*)$ /$1.php
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get that to work. I added some clarification to my original question, maybe that was the reason?

Comment: I don't get it. For example, if user is requesting url like "domain.com/products/something/whatever.php" then he will see content of the file "domain.com/something.php". Is that what you need?

Comment: And I have just tested htaccess with your code, and I have added my code - it works fine for me. Which kind of errors did you get?

Comment: Thanks IgorM, I'm not sure what was going on but I did eventually get it working using your code. Thanks for your answer, and your persistance!